# How to make android app load data from CSV to SQLite once?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am loading getting data from a csv file then inserting them into SQLite at the launch of my app but it does this every time I open my app. Is there a way that that the app will only iterate through the CSV only on the first use of the app so that the succeeding launches will be quicker?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you just include the pre-populated database with the app?

Comment: You can use Mike M. suggestion or you can query the database to see if you have some values in it from the `CSV` and if the `SELECT` will return  no record the you can import the `CSV`. Both of them will work

Comment: How can I include a pre-populated database? My CSV File contains around 800 rows. Sorry, I just started learning Android.

Comment: use shared preferences, save a boolean that is first set to false on first run, then set it to true after you've parsed/loaded your CSV Data. Put that shared prefs check in your 'onCreate` function. Just check that shared preference every time in your onCreate then execute every time it returns false (which will only happen once since you've set it to true afterwards..)

Comment: I think if you place that code (used to insert data) in `onCreate()` of your db-helper it will be executed once. also the above suggestions are very useful, why don't you share some relevant code so people can provide better answers for you

Comment: SavedPreferences worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to determine if you already parsed your csv file.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("someKey", "1");
editor.commit();
```

And before you run your task you should check if you had manipulated your csv already by checking if the "someKey" exsit.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can avoid to call for CSV file at each time.

You can save a small data (Saving Key-Value Sets) on the app setting using SharedPrefernce.

You can save a small int value on shared preference that indicates you have already called the CSV file or not.

At the beginning you have to call for the CSV load function with in a if conduction that checks whether the sharedpreference value has 1 or 0

if the shared pererence value has 0  the u will enter to the function and insert to the database. after that with in the if condition you will change the shared preference value to 1..

so the next time when you open the app, the shared preference value will be 1... if condition will not be satisfied.. the function will not be called...

Hope u understand